# Problema com o mysql_query, os dados não caem no banco SQL.

Tags: php, mysql, query

Olá,

Não consigo executar essa query, dei um echo nessa variável e todas os dados estão sendo passados, mas não entra no meu BD. Quando copio o comando e colo dentro da query do phpMyAdmin funciona. Alguém poderia dar um help? Valeu! :)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tabela2` (`nome`, `cor`, `sexo`) VALUES 
('$nome','$cor','$sexo')";

mysql_query($link,$sql);
```

Comment: ja tentou com mysqli ?

Comment: não, como eu faço?

Comment: `mysql_query()` essa função foi removida do php7, sua substituta é a `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Mas o versão do php no servidor é 5.6.30, posso usar mesmo assim?

Answer (score 3):

Você está utilizando o comando `mysql_query` de forma errada.

Segundo a documentação do PHP, a função [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-query.php) é definida por:

```
mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier ] )
```

Onde a string query deve ser o primeiro parâmetro e não o segundo, como você está fazendo.

---

Fica a sugestão de trocar as funções mysql, que estão obsoletas, por mysqli

Veja mais na própria documentação do PHP: [Extensão MySQL Melhorada](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
`$host = "localhost";
$user = "seu usuario";
$pass = "sua senha"
$db = "seu banco de dados";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);`


`$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela2 (nome,cor,sexo) VALUES ('$nome','$cor','$sexo')";
$inseriu = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);`
```

Comment: a ultima linha não deveria ser $inseriu = mysqli_query($sql, $conn); ?

Comment: nao amigo, primeiro a gente passa a conexao dps a inserção